# Why is difference between 2 Dates off by 1 minute if use Date()?

Tags: swift, date, swift-playground

For some reason when I use `Date()` (to get the current date) and then calculate the difference in time, it is always 1 minute off. However, when I hard code a date and calculate the difference in time, it is correct.

Why is that and how I can accurately calculate the difference between date right now (i.e. `currentDate`) and the date in the future (i.e. `date2`)?

To show you what I mean here is an playground example:
[image]

**Code**

```
let calendar = Calendar.current
var components = DateComponents()
components.day = 12
components.month = 2
components.year = 2017
components.hour = 19
components.minute = 50

let date1 = calendar.date(from: components)

components.hour = 20
components.minute = 30

let date2 = calendar.date(from: components)

let currentDate = Date()

let conversionInfoAccurate = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour, .minute, .day], from: date1!, to: date2!)
let daysAccurate = conversionInfoAccurate.day
let hoursAccurate = conversionInfoAccurate.hour
let minutesAccurate = conversionInfoAccurate.minute

let conversionInfo1Off = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour, .minute, .day], from: currentDate, to: date2!)
let days1Off = conversionInfo1Off.day
let hours1Off = conversionInfo1Off.hour
let minutes1Off = conversionInfo1Off.minute
```

Comment: because second is different?

Comment: Does `currentDate` have a seconds component?

Comment: All dates have second components. Or, rather, no date has components at all; decomposition is a function of the calendar.

Comment: @BryanChen No I'm saying if you look both `date1` and `currentDate` are set to 2/12/17  7:50 PM and `date2` is set to  2/12/17 8:30pm. Yet when you do `date2` - `date1` = 40 mins, but `date2` - `currentDate` = 39 mins

Comment: @JoshCaswell ohhh I see thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Date`s have precision to the level of milliseconds. Unless you are quite lucky, the result of `Date()` is some number of milliseconds (or even whole seconds) *after* the date you constructed from components. `assert(date1 != currentDate)`

Then when you ask for the difference, there are 39 *whole* minutes, and some number of seconds, from `currentDate`. The date you constructed falls exactly on the minute and there are 40 whole minutes between it and the other.